# can I rewind a 220 volts coil into 24 volts?

Tags: contactor

My machine's magnetic contactor needs replacement but it's quite difficult to buy a 24 volt coil magnetic contactor. Can I purchase a 220volt coil magnetic contactor and rewind the 220v coil into 24 volts? Can it be done with the existing wires?

Comment: Be careful with "can I..." questions. We don't know your skills so how can we judge what you can do (properly)? Also the main question is: Is it a good idea or not?

Comment: Can be done. There may even be a professional motor rewinder (or transformer mfg) in your area who can help. But the wire will be a thicker gauge.

Comment: I would determine what it takes to install a pilot relay with a 24 volt coil. That might turn out to be preferable.

Comment: Hard to buy 24v contactor, well I disagree, Do a web search and you will find many sources from Amazon to your local electrical store.

Comment: A 220V contactor is presumably designed for AC with a slightly different magnetic circuit than for DC. It may not work expected.

Comment: 24V AC is used used in many biulding thermostat circuits.

Answer (score 3):

I have in the past rewound magnetic machines (like relays) to operate at lower voltage.

I rewound a 24V counter to 12V by unwinding the coil folding it in half and winding it back on connecting the original two ends to one terminal and the midpoint to the other.

A 220V contactor will have very fine wire so you'll need to be careful when handling the wire. you'll probably need tools and materials to splice it when it breaks. (sandpaper, soldering iron, flux, solder, and lacquer)

\$ 220 \div 9 = 24 {4\over9}\$ (which is probably close enough to 24) so you should divide the wire into nine equal pieces and wind the coil with nine strands of the original coil in parallel.

Twisting the strands into a "rope" before winding may make the process easier.

If you started with a contactor with an AC coil the new contactor will still want AC.